# C++ Windows Forms Calculator

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a windows forms calculator using C++ but I've run into a problem, and although I know where the error lies, I can not work out how to fix it.

When adding two values together, I get the correct result. However, if I continue to press the equals button, it adds the first number to the result instead of the second. For example, if I did 2 + 3 = 5, then pressed equals again, it would add 2 rather than 3, resulting in 7. Really, the second input should be added to the result.

Also, if I use the + operator when a result is displayed, that result is then stored within the firstNum variable. With the result of that equation being stored in the secondNum variable.

Below is my code. I understand that when I press an operation, it stores that value inside of the firstNum variable. When I press equals, it stores the current result in secondNum. I'm just not sure how to fix it. I'm sorry if this post is confusing.

```
double firstNum;
double secondNum;
double resultNumber;
double result;
String^ calOperator;
char calOperation;

private: System::Void operationsClick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

Button^ operation = safe_cast<Button^>(sender);
firstNum = double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);
txtDisplay->Text = "";

calOperator = operation->Text;

lblOperation->Text = System::Convert::ToString(firstNum) + " " + calOperator;
lblOperation->Visible = true;
}

private: System::Void btnEquals_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
Maths math = Maths();
secondNum = double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);

lblOperation->Text = System::Convert::ToString(firstNum) + " " + calOperator + " " + System::Convert::ToString(secondNum);
lblOperation->Visible = true;

if (calOperator == "+")
{
    result = math.Add(firstNum, secondNum);
    txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(result);
}
}
```

[Addition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWudT.png)

[Addition 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0HDP.png) < 2 gets added on to 5, rather than 3.

[Addition 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slK6p.png) < I press "+" and add 5 to the result. Which displays the correct result...

[Addition 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D54by.png) ...However, the secondNum is constantly replaced by the result. Rather than staying at 5 and continuously adding 5 to the result.

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of an image.

Comment: You seem to be parsing the entire displaytext value, which is why it gives you the value of 2.  You will need to split your displaytext text first and parse whatever is on the right of the operator

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you provide me with a fix for this, please?

Comment: This is not C++ but C++/CLI. If you don't use some third party C++ libraries or C++ legacy code then there is no reason to use C++/CLI, and you would be better of with C#. As for your actual problem try adding this after `math.Add`: `firstNum = result;`. Windows calculator gives this after 2+3=,=,=,=: 5, 8, 11, 14, so `secondNum` should not actually change.

Comment: So assigning to `secondNum` at function start should not be done if `btnEquals` is last clicked button (and you need a separate bool flag to keep track of this).

Answer (score 0):

The problems is for the same event (button press) you need to do two different things depending at different times.

The first time equals is pressed, you need to get the second addend (fancy talk for "thing you're adding") and add it to the first addend.

Each subsequent time you press equals, you want to continue to add the second addend to the result. Here you can't do that unless you maintain state somehow.

A quick and dirty method is to have a boolean state variable indicating "firstTimeCalculating" that tracks the difference between the two above states and takes action appropriatesly.

A better method would be to create a state machine of sorts composed of a state transition table, which works as follows:

Each row of the table indicates a "transition", which does nothing more than explains "When you get this event, if you are in state X, transition to state Y then call this function Zed"

This way, you can eliminate the boolean I first mentioned and rely instead on a state variable to indicate if the first sum has been calculated or not, and if so what to do in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, do you have an example by any chance? I just want the calculator to work like the windows calculator, where it adds the second input to the current result. Mine just adds the first input constantly, then stores the result in the second input and it's one big mess.

Comment: The simplest example would be to have a state variable and a switch statement contained in a function called "evaluate" which is called when the equals sign is pressed. The first state (after the second addend is entered and the equals button is pressed for the first time) may be called something sensical like "initial", which will evaluate X + Y before changing the state to "subsequent", where in subsequent, X is set to X + Y (the display) and Y remains the second addend, so the handler here only adds X + Y still, although X is the previous sum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that firstNum always stays the same and secondNum is always updated to the latest result in the display.

What you need to do is set the value of secondNum once and then not change it ever again.

After the first calculation was processed, you no longer need the original value of firstNum, all that matters is the original value of secondNum and the last result which is in txtDisplay->Text.

You could have a flag that is set to 0 when the calculation is initiated for the first time, and then set it to 1 after the calculation was completed for the first time.

The process would go something like this:

1) when operationsClick() is called, set a bool or int variable to false or 0.

2) when btnEquals_Click() is called for the first time, do the math.Add(firstNum, secondNum) as usual. After the calculation, check whether the flag variable is 0/false or 1/true.

It will be 0/false, so secondNum is the original second value that was entered, and the original firstNum value will no longer be needed from now on -- so store secondNum into firstNum. Then set the flag variable to 1/true.

3) when btnEquals_Click() is called again, do the math.Add(firstNum, secondNum) as usual. After the calculation, check whether the flag variable is 0/false or 1/true.

It will now be 1/true, so secondNum is no longer the original value -- so DON'T store it into firstNum.

In code:

```
double firstNum;
double secondNum;
double resultNumber;
double result;
String^ calOperator;
char calOperation;

// Add a bool variable that we use as status flag
bool wasCalculatedBefore;

private: System::Void operationsClick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    Button^ operation = safe_cast<Button^>(sender);
    firstNum = double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);
    txtDisplay->Text = "";

    calOperator = operation->Text;

    lblOperation->Text = System::Convert::ToString(firstNum) + " " + calOperator;
    lblOperation->Visible = true;

    // Here we reset the flag to false.
    // This reflects that we haven't done a full calculation yet.
    wasCalculatedBefore = false;
}

private: System::Void btnEquals_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    Maths math = Maths();
    secondNum = double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);

    lblOperation->Text = System::Convert::ToString(firstNum) + " " + calOperator + " " + System::Convert::ToString(secondNum);
    lblOperation->Visible = true;

    if (calOperator == "+")
    {
        result = math.Add(firstNum, secondNum);
        txtDisplay->Text = System::Convert::ToString(result);
    }

    // Check the status of the flag here.
    // If this is the first time the calculation was processed...
    if (wasCalculatedBefore == false)
    {
        // ...use firstNum as a buffer for original secondNum
        firstNum = secondNum;
        // and update the flag variable so this doesn't happen
        // again if btnEquals_Click() is called repeatedly from
        // now on.
        wasCalculatedBefore = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, it still doesn't seem to work for me. The first number constantly gets added to the result, then when I press the + operator for the second time, the result gets stored within the firstNum variable. The secondNum variable then becomes the updated result every time I press the = operator.

Comment: Sorry, but that's the way a calculator works.

Enter 10, hit + then enter 5.
Hit = once will add 10+5 and output the result 15.
Hit = repeatedly, and always 5 will be added to the previous result.
Hit + again, and the current result will become firstNum.
Enter another number and that will become the new secondNum.
Hit = once, and the new secondNum will be added to the previous result in firstNum.
Hit = repeatedly, and the new secondNum will be added to the latest result repeatedly, just as before.

If you don't believe me, try it in your operating system's calculator app. :)

Comment: That's what I want to happen but it's not. If I add 2 + 3 I get 5. When I press = again, it should add 3 and result in 8. Instead, it adds 2 and I get 7. Once I'm at 7, if I press + 8 I get 15. = again, I get 22. It should add + 8 again to 15 and get 23 (just tested it on windows calculator). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: With the code I posted, what you describe CAN NOT happen. Every time you press + the currently displayed result will be stored in firstNum. Every time you press = the currently displayed value will be stored in secondNum. If it's the first time = is pressed after + then firstNum will become the secondNum value, so there is no possibility of adding the original firstNum value again.

Comment: Ahh okay. Is there any way to do it the way I described? Sorry to be a pain. Once the addition is complete I can use the code for subtraction, multiplication and division using the same method I'd assume.

Comment: You said in a comment to another answer that you want your calculator to work like the Windows Calculator. The code snippet I have provided does exactly that. I have moved the flag switching out of the calOperator if block so that you can easier extend it with else-if statements for other operators. With those, it will also work exactly like the Windows Calculator application. Use the code I have provided, it will work. Reset the flag to false in operationsClick(), and after the calculation is done you copy secondNum to firstNum & set the flag true. Next operationsClick() it starts again.